# Removing the toolbar from Sencha Picker

Tags: extjs, toolbar, picker

I am trying to remove the toolbar from Sencha Picker (I only need the scrolling area with the event 'pick') - but nothing seems to work. The problem is that we must copy the sencha docs code of Picker (WITH slotpicker code) and try to remove it from there. However - this doesn't work and removed the whole slot area. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the toolbar invisible

```
toolbar: {
    hidden: true
}
```

BTW why not just to do

```
doneButton: false,
cancelButton: false,
toolbar: {
    ui: 'light',
    title: 'My Picker!'
}
```

?

Comment: That works, The problem with Sencha is that I couldn't guess we have this option... I had to ask you

Comment: Sencha has got a [good documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Picker).

Comment: That is right, however - from that - you still should have **GUESSED** you can do the hidden trick...